# In a WinJS Windows 8 app, how can I change the highlight color of the selected item in a listview?

Tags: css, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, winjs

I want to change the CSS style when a WinJS Listivew item is selected, like in the picture.

[image]

Basically I would like the purple part to be grey, and this should to be done via CSS I guess because we are in WinJS.

```
win-selectionborder
win-selectionbackground
win-selectionhint
win-selectioncheckmark
win-selectioncheckmarkbackground
```

I've tried them all, but they all give strange results, changing everything but that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the images from Chapter 5 of my free ebook, [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, Second Edition*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2), where I show how all the styles related to the checkbox. These are specifically in the section called "Styling Gallery: WinJS Controls". In these images I show the default styling as compared with custom styling. You'll see that the trick is really having the right selectors for the styling hierarchy, as it's often not just a single class you have to concern yourself with. Note also that the use of .win-selectionstylefilled distinguishes between that and the outline style.

Also note that the styles I show here are not scoped to a particular list or page; gbellman's answer gives some of that.

[image: item container styling 1]

[image: item container styling 2]

[image: item container styling 3]

Comment: thanks, this is way more info that I could find on microsoft website

Comment: Which is one of the main reasons I wrote the book, so there'd be a place with the consolidated details.

Answer (score 0):

WinJS is a complex maze of CSS. Here is what I recommend. Open up your project in the element inspector (Internet Explorer 10 or 11) via the project. Then you can place your cursor over the element and trace back up the CSS chain to figure out where the color is being modified.

It's the only easy way I was able to do this on our project. I eventually had to write a lot of custom CSS to override certain design elements, but this only worked when I truly understood what properties are being inherited where via the CSS...

Comment: well this is exactly what I did but if it was so easy I wouldn'st have written a question here. :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.pageName .listViewName .win-container .win-selectionbackground {
    background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192); /* your color here */
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Comment: mmm not for me. it colors only part of it

Comment: Add an important  !important

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the elements using DOM explorer and look into ui-light.css or ui-dark.css to override some selectors.